# Source code of pig in CDH3 Vmware image

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I am using cloudera cdh3 vmware image to run pig scripts from the prompt. I am trying to look at the source code from the ubuntu. I am looking to add some operators in the source code. So, I want to look at files like POPackage.java, POLocalrearrange.java etc.., Can somebody point out the source directory on the image in directory hierarchy. Like I want to navigate to folders like src/org/apache/pig/backend. Is this possible or cloudera uses all files as jars??
As I did a find and didn't find any files.
Thanks

Comment: Is the code you're interested in packaged in Ubuntu?

Comment: yeah I am using vmware image packaged using ubuntu..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to the specific need of the question, the CDH3 image uses pig and hadoop jars packed and all dependencies resolved. So, the source code of the system cannot be viewed as the code is packed as jars. It can be installed manually very easily if you are making changes to the source code like adding operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-get source <package>` to download the sourcecode for nearly everything installed on Ubuntu; you just need the corresponding `deb-src` lines in your `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
...
```

You can find the package that owns a specific file using `dpkg -S`:

```
$ dpkg -S `readlink -f /usr/bin/vim`
vim-gtk: /usr/bin/vim.gtk
```

Running `apt-get source vim-gtk` will download and unpack the source from the `vim` source package.

Comment: I don't want the source code for that...I wanted to know if that was compiled from source code and the location of the source code on that particular machine...or is the software installed using jars?

Comment: `vim` was just an example. Obviously, use whatever package you're interested in...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I really appreciate your input. But, what I was looking for was different as I wan to modify the core code and see the changes. The conf files were then configured using jars...Thank You so much